# Can I do a `has_many through` on foreign key in the through relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have three models - `User, Membership, Connection`, they look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"
  has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "membership_id"
  belongs_to :invited_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "invited_membership_id"
end
```

But...what I would like to do is setup a direct connection from `user` to `connections`. So, ideally I would like to be able to do `user.invited_connections` or `user.inviter_connections` and they would correspond to the right connections.

i.e. `user.invited_connections` would correspond to the connections where the `membership.user_id == current_user.id` (but keep in mind it is the connections associated with that membership record that is associated with that `user_id`...not just the memberships associated with that `user_id`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
has_many :invited_connections, through: :memberships, source: :invited_membership
has_many :inviter_connections, through: :memberships, source: :inviter_membership
```

Cheers!